# how to add some links in bottom page in overleaf

Tags: footnotes

I added link to overleaf used \footnote {http://edu.gaitech.hk/ria_e100/index.html} but gave me error in overleaf. I need to do like this [image]

please help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not know overleaf but I would write something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is a fake text\footnote{\url{https://www.google.com/}}
\end{document}
```

to obtain what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is ok now